# Support for Aspect Oriented Programming missing from new IModule interface in Prism7.1

Tags: wpf, prism

How do I set virtual method interceptors while registering the ViewModels in the RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)

I would like to do something like this, but I cant do it with the "containerRegistry"

```
public override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
 Container.Configure<Interception>()
.SetInterceptorFor<SomeViewModel>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GetContainer` on the container abstraction you receive from prism to get the actual container:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor<SomeViewModel>(new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
```

Comment: The IContainerRegistry interface in IModule, doesn't have a method GetContainer().
I suppose that's available as an extension method in PrismIocExtensions. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use the extension method that matches your container (each `PrismApplication` brings along its own `PrismIocExtensions`).